# codeigniter session is not working in constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Here is the code to store session data if `$result` is not false..and redirect user based on the previous session value if `$result` is false.

But the problem is   the session value are showing `empty` or `false` in the else condition of the code above and and showing proper data if the `$result` is true but not working when the `$result` is false.

When the `$result` is `true` it sets the `session` and works as aspected.. but when the `$result` is `false` it is not even showing me session value which i `have already` assign when the `$result` is true.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $result = $this->extractdomain->extract(site_url());
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $session_user = array(
            'location' => $result,
            'urlParams' => $this->uri->uri_string()
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_user);
        var_dump($this->session->userdata('location'));

    } else {
        $redirectUrl = $this->session->userdata('location') ? $this->session->userdata('location') . '.' : '';
        $urlParams = $this->session->userdata('urlParams') ? $this->session->userdata('urlParams') : '';
        var_dump($this->session->userdata('location'));
        var_dump($redirectUrl);
        var_dump($urlParams);
        //$url = 'http://' . $redirectUrl . 'mydomain.in' . $urlParams;
        //redirect($url);
    }
}
```

extractdomain code:

```
function extract($domain) {
    $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $domain);
    $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];

    $subdomain_name = explode('http://', $subdomain_name);

    if ($subdomain_name[1] == "mydomain") {
        return "India";
    } else {
        $location = array('mumbai','goa','delhi','pune');
        if(in_array($subdomain_name[1], $location)){
            return ucfirst($subdomain_name[1]);
        }
        else{
            return '';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where are you loading extractdomain?

Comment: this method returns `FALSE` or `someStringdata`.. the `extractdomain` is not the issue.. its just return false or string.. based on the condition.. i have written

Comment: see, try providing the $result hardcoded values true or false, its working good. which means there is surely some problem with extractdomain

Comment: @sunny tried as you suggested.. but no change same issue...

Comment: but i am getting the session values when i am not using extractdomain. ok just me.. what result do you get by extract? boolean or string? if its not boolean then try checking by condition if!empty($result)

Comment: @sunny tried as you suggested.. but again same issue...

Comment: this doesn't really answer your issue, have you looked at using the parse_url PHP function http://www.php.net/parse_url in place of the extractdomain class. Ignore me if that is what the extractdomain is already doing :)

Comment: You say that 'extractdomain' is not the issue...but it seems to be. Can you at least provide the code for us to have a look at?  Since you aren't sure what the issue is...it's plausible that that IS the issue.

Comment: Thanks every one.. for your important time..! .. now i have also included the `extractdomain` code.. in the question..!!!!

Comment: @kevindeleon Sir i have updated the question.. please have a look..

Comment: @mic sir, basically i wanted to get the value of subdomain from the url.. the url can be. `emaxple.mydomain.in` or `example2.emxaple1.example.mydomain.in` and i only wanted to get the value of first subdomain from right side..consider this `example2.emxaple1.example.mydomain.in` i would like to get the `example` and ignoring the `example2.emxaple1` subdomains from the url..and if no subdomains exists.. then i would like to get the `mydomain` part from the url.. please help..